# how to install PCL (point cloud library) v 1.9 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I was trying to run this on my pc, and I unable to install

https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Perception-Exercises

Ubuntu 20.04
python 3.8

Comment: I assume you have already installed it or does run mean install? Please be clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) ← for successful `pcl-tools` package installation, or please add details.

Comment: @David I had install PCL v 1.12 but when i Built it, it give this error                setup.py: error: cannot find PCL, tried
    pkg-config pcl_common-1.9
    pkg-config pcl_common-1.8
    pkg-config pcl_common-1.7
    pkg-config pcl_common

Comment: @N0rbert  i have tried that not working

Comment: Please add reproducible steps to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert i have followed the steps from the repo

Comment: "RoboND-Perception-Exercises" is four year old code, python 2 only, and pcl <=1.9 . ( Ubuntu 20.04 has pcl version 1.10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [repository](https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Perception-Exercises) is from 2017 year, but now is 2021.

So I would recommend to use `python3-pcl` package from [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-pcl) as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pcl pcl-tools
```

And then use code from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install git

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Perception-Exercises.git
cd RoboND-Perception-Exercises

# check Exercise-1
cd Exercise-1/
python3 RANSAC.py
```

Please note that for Exercise-2 and Exercise-3 you need some ROS-specific packages for `pcl_rosConfig.cmake`. Start with

```
sudo apt-get install cmake catkin python3-catkin libdynamic-reconfigure-config-init-mutex-dev libpcl-conversions-dev
```